# tf_gather_nd and tensor_scatter_nd_update on batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, gpu

I am struggling with tf_gather_nd and tensor_scatter_nd_update.

**First:**
I am trying to index into a batch of tensors. The params tensor has the dimension (4, 64, 2) and my original indices tensor has the dimension (4, 64). I have been able to solve this problem by inserting the indices 0 to 63 into my original indices tensor.

```
idx = np.array([i for i in range(64)])
indices_adj = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.stack([idx, x], axis=1), indices)
tf.gather_nd(params, indices_adj, batch_dims=1)
```

However, I am wondering if there is a better solution than this?

**Second:** I also need to update the batch of tensors of dimension (4, 64, 2) with values in a (4, 64) tensor at indices provided in a (4, 64) tensor. However, since tensor_scatter_nd_update does not provide any batch functionality like tf_gather_nd, I have no idea how to efficiently implement this.

Before dealing with batches, my code simply looked like this:

```
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(params, tf.stack([idx, indices], axis=1), update)
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first operation you want to do can be simply done like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(0)
params = tf.random.uniform([4, 64, 2])
idx = tf.random.uniform([4, 64], 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
out = tf.gather_nd(params, tf.expand_dims(idx, -1), batch_dims=2)
print(out.shape)
# (4, 64)
```

For the second one you need to build the complete multidimensional index:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(0)
params = tf.random.uniform([4, 64, 2])
idx = tf.random.uniform([4, 64], 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
update = tf.random.uniform([4, 64])
s = tf.shape(idx, out_type=idx.dtype)
ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(s[0]), tf.range(s[1]), indexing='ij')
idx_comp = tf.stack([ii, jj, idx], axis=-1)
out = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(params, idx_comp, update)
```

Although in the particular case where your last dimension has two elements you can use this equivalent operation too:

```py
update_t = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(update, axis=-1), [1, 1, 2])
idx_t = tf.stack([idx, 1 - idx], axis=-1)
out = tf.where(tf.dtypes.cast(idx_t, tf.bool), params, update_t)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!!
In the meantime, I have solved it by concatenating everything ([4, 64, 2] -> [256, 2] and then reshaping the result back to [4, 64]. This seems to perform similar to your suggestion (in terms of execution time), but feels less clean.

I now adopted your suggestion and it works perfectly.